# Using Twig in Symfony 2: Translation inside an embeded block does not work

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

I am using `Twig` inside my `Symfony 2` WebApp project. I use `{% embed SomeTamplate %}` to include the content of one template file in another. This workes fine, but translation is not working inside the embedded file.

**Page Template:**

```
{% extends 'AppBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% trans_default_domain mypages' %}

1: {{ 'pages.home.sometext'|trans }}

{% embed "block.html.twig" with {'classes': 'homepage-hero'} %}
    {% block content %}
        2: {{ 'pages.home.sometext'|trans }}
    {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}

{% embed "block.html.twig" with {'classes': 'red-bg'} %}
    {% block content %}
        3: {{ 'pages.home.sometext'|trans }}
    {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

**Block template:**

```
{% trans_default_domain mypages' %}

<div class="full-width-block{% if classes is defined %} {{ classes }}{% endif %}">
    X: {{ 'pages.home.sometext'|trans }}

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

**Output:**

```
1: SomeText

X: SomeText
2: pages.home.sometext

X: SomeText
3: pages.home.sometext
```

So: While the translation works fine within the two template files, the same text constant within the embedded block, is not translated. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the domain must be enclosed in quotes, just put the last quotation mark.
Visit http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html

Put it this way:

{% trans_default_domain "mypages" %}

I hope your problem is solved